# Efficiently search for pairs of numbers in various rows

Tags: algorithm, optimization, graph

Imagine you have N distinct people and that you have a record of where these people are, exactly M of these records to be exact.

For example

```
1,50,299
1,2,3,4,5,50,287
1,50,299
```

So you can see that 'person 1' is at the same place with 'person 50' three times. Here M = 3 obviously since there's only 3 lines. My question is given M of these lines, and a threshold value (i.e person A and B have been at the same place more than threshold times), what do you suggest the most efficient way of returning these co-occurrences?

So far I've built an N by N table, and looped through each row, incrementing table(N,M) every time N co occurs with M in a row. Obviously this is an awful approach and takes 0(n^2) to O(n^3) depending on how you implent. Any tips would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to create the table.  Just create a hash/dictionary/whatever your language calls it.  Then in pseudocode:

```
answer = []
for S in sets:
    for (i, j) in pairs from S:
        count[(i,j)]++
        if threshold == count[(i,j)]:
            answer.append((i,j))
```

If you have `M` sets of size of size `K` the running time will be `O(M*K^2)`.

If you want you can actually keep the list of intersecting sets in a data structure parallel to `count` without changing the big-O.

Furthermore the same algorithm can be readily implemented in a distributed way using a map-reduce.  For the count you just have to emit a key of `(i, j)` and a value of `1`.  In the reduce you count them.  Actually generating the list of sets is similar.

Answer (score 0):

The known concept for your case is Market Basket analysis. In this context, there are different algorithms. For example [Apriori algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apriori_algorithm) can be using for your case in a specific case for sets of size 2.

Moreover, in these cases to finding [association rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Association_rule_learning) with specific supports and conditions (which for your case is the threshold value) using from LSH and min-hash too.

Comment: thanks for telling me the actual name of the concept! However, upon looking at a few articles on that topic, it doesn't seem to offer any solution better than O(N^2*M), which is my main concern.

Answer (score 0):

you could use probability to speed it up, e.g. only check each pair with 1/50 probability. That will give you a 50x speed up. Then double check any pairs that make it close enough to 1/50th of M.

To double check any pairs, you can either go through the whole list again, or you could double check more efficiently if you do some clever kind of reverse indexing as you go. e.g. encode each persons row indices into 64 bit integers, you could use binary search / merge sort type techniques to see which 64 bit integers to compare, and use bit operations to compare 64 bit integers for matches. Other things to look up could be reverse indexing, binary indexed range trees / fenwick trees.

Comment: can you explain what you mean by check each pair with 1/50 probability ?